# Create list with data from grouped Linq query plus related data from another table

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, devexpress-wpf

I have two entities witch are related by DataID.
What I need is, to get a list, or two lists to pass data to WPF form to display.

```
    public class Journal
    {
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}


    public int DataID {get; set;}
[ForeignKey("DataID")]   
 public virtual JournalData JournalData { get; set; }
    }

    Public class JournalData
    {
    [Key]
    public int DataID {get; set;}
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    }

First of all I created a lists 
List<Journal>
List<JournalData>
```

When I'v tried to get data from Journal grouped by DataID

```
List<Journal> result = query
                    .GroupBy(t => t.DataID)
                    .Select(g => new { DataID = g.Key})
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(t => new Journal() { DatatID = t.DataID })
                    .ToList();
```

I have only DataID and now I want to add data from JournalData where DataID =t.DataID

Could You please help me? Mabe the is a way to get related data through relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to `include` `JournalData` in your query

you will need to add following namespace

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Something like this (not tested)

```
List<Journal> result = query
                .Include(t => t.JournalData)
                .GroupBy(t => t.DataID)
                .Select(g => new { DataID = g.Key, JornalData = g.JournalData})
                .ToList()
                .Select(t => new Journal() { DatatID = t.DataID, JournalData = t.JournalData })
                .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

```
var result = query.Include(t => t.JournalData)
                  .GroupBy(g => g.DataID)                     
                  .Select(g => new { DataID = g.Key, JournalData = g.Select(j => j.JournalData) })
                  .ToList();
```

**EDIT2**
if you want field1, field2 next to DataID something like this

```
var result = journals.GroupBy(g => g.DataID)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    DataID = g.Key,                     
                    Fields = g.Select(j => new { Field1 = j.JournalData.Field1, Field2 = j.JournalData.Field2}) 
                })                  
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I can't see JournalData      .Select(g => new {DataID = g.Key, JournalData ...  Here I also nees Field1 and Field2 values :(

Comment: I can't see  othet tables data :(  .Include(t => t.JournalData)

Comment: And how to get these values "Field1" "Field2" near DataID in a list witch I can pass to WPF form?

Comment: Hi @Songaila I will provide a final update but it should really be a new question otherwise comments will go on forever and become unreadable. Please mark as correct answer thx

Comment: Thanks... I can't find where to mark You answer as a correct answer :(

Comment: Hi you click the grey tick.on the top left of the answer :) thx

Comment: Now I see :) sorry so about WPF form I should post another question, yes?

Comment: Yes post another question I will try and have a look this morning